# Error with finding the 10001th prime number

Tags: c++, math

I am currently trying to solve one of project euler's problems, to find the 10001st prime number. Though my code is not returning the right number, and even returned a even number when I changed the starting value of 'count'. Below is my code, if anyone could help me out with this it would be appreciated.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdbool.h>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int num);

int main()
{
    int num = 0, count = 0;
    while(count < 10001)
    {
        num++;
        while(isPrime(num) != true)
        {
               num++;
               cout << "\n num: " << num;   
        }
        count++;
        isPrime(12);
    }
    cout << "the 10001's prime number is: " << num << "\n " << count;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


bool isPrime(int num)
{
       bool checkPrime = false;
       if(num%2 != 0)
       {
              for(int i = 3; i <= sqrt(num); i++)
              {
                      if(num%i != 0)
                      {
                              checkPrime = true;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          checkPrime = false;
                          break;   
                      }       
              }  
       }
       else
       {
           return false;   
       }
       if(checkPrime)
       {
              return true;    
       }
       else
       {
           return false;    
       }      
}
```

Comment: Please replace that last if-statement with simply `return checkPrime;`. And don't repeatedly calculate `sqrt(num)`, it's an expensive operation. Just calculate it once and store the result. And `isPrime(num) != true` can be replaced by `!isPrime(num)`.

Comment: It will be simpler and faster to implement this using standard [Eratosthenes sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes): it would require only 150000 bytes (which can be compressed to bits, or 19KB)

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie [The 10000's prime is 104729](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt), so I would hope so.

Comment: It sure does - it is 104743

Comment: Ok thanks Dukeling, I have made those changes you suggested, my program is currently returning 104779, anyone can guess why it isn't working correctly?

Comment: @WillGolledge Because your isPrime function returns the wrong value for a few small primes, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic in isPrime is wrong. isPrime(3) returns false for instance. The basic problem is that you initialize checkPrime to false instead of true, so that any small number which doesn't enter your for loop returns false even if it's a prime.

Here's a (hopefully) correct version, also with some of the changes Dukeling suggested.

```
bool isPrime(int num)
{
    if (num < 2) // numbers less than 2 are a special case
        return false;
    bool checkPrime = true; // change here
    int limit = sqrt(num);
    for (int i = 2; i <= limit; i++)
    {
        if (num%i == 0)
        {
            checkPrime = false;
            break;   
        }       
    }  
    return checkPrime;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much John, this now returns the correct answer. I really need to learn to code on a lot less lines haha

Comment: @WillGolledge Often the simpler code is also the correct code.

Comment: You don't need to check every number to see whether it's a factor, just the list of previously found primes.